# Drawing tree diagram in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drawing

I am creating an web application for my tae kwon do club.

People are able to register online for a tournament.

After the registration deadline the web application generates a dendrogram. Something like this:

[image: http://img197.imageshack.us/i/dendrogram6bw.jpg/.]

I am wondering now how to draw it.

Because of the fact that there are my weight and age categories i have to draw them dynamicly for each group.

What is the easiest way to draw this inside a MVC view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have two choices:

1. Draw it on the server using gdi and sending the resultant bitmap over the pipe to the browser.
2. Draw it on the client using canvas. If you can control the browser that is being used, this may not be a bad idea. Otherwise, stick with the server side rendering.

Although it looks like you could do it using borders around HTML elements, I wouldn't. By the time you fight those battles, you could have the server side rendering done.

Hope this helps to get you started.

Bob

Comment: I vote for the canvas solution. This is the correct application of it, if people use shitty web browsers that's too bad for them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw an image on the server, then just send it to the browser as a .jpg, See if [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) will do what you need.  It's not specific to dendrograms, but i think it's probably flexible enough to do it.